# Remover nome do parâmetro URL MVC

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Tenho o seguinte URL

> /vlog/usertimeline/?slug=testes

para o controller Vlog, action usertimeline e parâmetro slug.
Como devo configurar a rota para que fique

> /vlog/usertimeline/testes

Estou usando MVC 4.

Tenho as seguintes rotas configuradas:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "PubServices",
            "PubServices/{action}",
            new { controller = "PubServices", action = "Index" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "MailsJson",
            "MailsJson/{action}",
            new { controller = "MailsJson", action = "Index" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults

        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Company",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Company", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults

        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "RecoverPasswordFinish",
            "Account/RecoverPasswordFinish/{username}/{hash}",
            new { Controller = "AccountWF", action = "RecoverPasswordFinish" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "EmailConfirmation",
            "AccountWF/EmailConfirmation/{username}/{userid}",
            new { Controller = "AccountWF", action = "EmailConfirmation" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "UnsubscribeBulkEmail",
            "Mails/UnsubscribeBulkEmail/{id}",
            new { Controller = "Mails", action = "UnsubscribeBulkEmail", id = "" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(

             "VlogTimeline",
             "Vlog/Timeline/{slug}",
             new { controller = "Vlog", action = "Timeline", slug = "" }

            );
```

Comment: se montou alguma rota?

Comment: para esse controller não tenho nada. existem umas rotas para outros controllers/métodos, mas já estavam no projeto no qual estou a trabalhar.

Comment: vai ter que criar uma rota para que ele possa fazer isso, e também verificar o conjuntos de rotas se não tem alguma igual. tem como colocar o arquivo de rotas na sua pergunta? e o controller/action respectivos ?

Comment: infelizmente não posso colar aqui o código, visto que se trata de um produto que não exclusivamente meu. Qual é a lógica que se usa para esconder esse slug? o meu metodo está assim: `public ActionResult usertimeline(string slug = "")`

Comment: Sem compartilhar o código fica dificil ajudar, mas tente utilizar os atributos [Route("")] para configurar.

Comment: Pode usar assim como base:  routes.MapRoute(
            "Company",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{slug}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Company", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults

        );

Answer (score 2):

Para montar uma rota especifica é o seguinte:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "vlog_usertimeline_slug",
            "/vlog/usertimeline/{slug}",
            new { Controller = "Vlog", action = "UserTimeline", 
                  slug = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

ou

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "vlog_2",
            url: "/vlog/usertimeline/{slug}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Vlog", action = "TestUrl" } ,
            constraints: new { slug = ".+" }
        );
```

Comment: coloquei a sua implementação mas não deu certo, editei a pergunta e meti todas as rotas

Comment: @ihavenokia as suas rotas já tem problemas elas estão repetindo rotas, mas diz aí o que não funcionou

Comment: se eu não colocar ?slug= nuca chega ao método, parece que não reconhece que o que vem é o slug, se eu não especificar..

Comment: Qual é o Controller e o método @ihavenokia

Comment: VlogController UserTimeline

Comment: @ihavenokia a minha resposta está correta não tem por onde, apesar que no seu arquivo de routas tem duas rotas iguais Company e Default, não pode.

Comment: a rota default tem que ser a ultima, pois as `URL's` "casam" com ela, acredito que seja por isso que não esteja entrando. No caso, como tem duas `defaults` iguais, ambas deveriam estar por ultimo

Comment: O grande problema @Barbetta e que as rotas dele também não seguem um padrão, apesar do seu detalhe mesmo assim não pode ter duas rotas iguais, e está acontecendo isso.